# GeoPandas の LineString の距離

Tags: python

GeoPandas の LineString の距離を **メートル** で求めたいです。

公開されているデータの座標系が JGD2011 で、 `dgf.geometry.length` によって求められる値は緯度経度の距離になります。

これをメートルで求める方法はありますか。